# How to merge files in a directory with r? (using Multmerge() function)

Tags: r, merge, directory, missing-data

I have a folder with 10 excel sheets. I want to merge those excel sheets so I'm using the code below:

```
library(DescTools)
Unit3 = multmerge("~/OneDrive - The Ohio State University/3. PROJECTS/X PROJECT/AU21/ES P1200 Raw Survey Data Ungraded/AU21Unit3")
```

The code is supposed to merge all the excel sheets in the folder "AU21Unit3" (which is specified in the code). HOWEVER, when I run the above code, I only get 25 participants in my newly named "Unit 3" file when I have 204 participants total. Data is getting lost and I am not sure how to resolve the issue.

R is reading the individual excel files in the folder AU21Unit3 correctly as I can see all the data when I pull up the files separately. Most data just somehow gets lost when I merge them with the code above. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, are all the excel sheets the same dimentions? (same number of rows? same number of columns? Each row is a participant??

Comment: What package is the `multmerge` function from? That's not a function in base R. Are you sure that's the right syntax for the function? How exactly did you check that R is reading all the right files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `library(DescTools)` package, but do you need to include the .xls or .xlsx suffix to the end of the path strting e.g. ".../AU21Unit3.xlsx" ? Looking further, the only `multmerge()` documentation I could find only merged files after they were imported to R.

Comment: `import_list` of package {rio} might be helpful. Supply the Excel file names and the sheet to import like `import_list(file = dir(path = 'path_to_your_dir', pattern = 'xlsx'), which = 'sheetname', ...)`

Comment: Hi @juan_bzt, apologies, they are actually CSV files. They have the same number of columns; Each column is a participant so each CSV file has the same participants. However, each CSV file has different data for the same participants (different measures which they answered). All files except for one has the same number of rows but even if I take out the CSV file that is inconsistent with the rest, they still won't merge properly.

Comment: @MrFlick, I don't think it belongs to a specific package since I don't have to load anything from my library to run the code. I got the multmerge function (and code) from a previous lab mate so I am not too familiar. I also checked by calling each CSV file into R, doing the View() function, and making sure all data was there (it was).

Comment: Hi @Ariana, I am not familiar with the desctools package, but if you are Rstudio, you can load each csv from the "import" tab, and then you can stack one on top of each other, with the `rbind` function. It is not the most elegant solution, but it will solve your problem.